# Could not find `CollectiveEvents` in `pallet_contracts`

Tags: substrate-contracts-node, pallet-contracts

**Error:**

```
const CONTRACTS_EVENTS: pallet_contracts::CollectEvents =
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `pallet_contracts
```

`Cargo.toml` File

```
pallet-contracts = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.42" }
pallet-contracts-primitives = { version = "7.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.42" }
```

`runtime -> src -> lib.rs` file

```
const CONTRACTS_EVENTS: pallet_contracts::CollectEvents =
pallet_contracts::CollectEvents::UnsafeCollect;
```

Answer (score 0):

If pallet_contracts is a configuration, add the following code snippet to your lib.rs:

```
Pallet_Contracts::<T,I>::CollectiveEvent
```

If pallet_contracts is a function, add the following code snippet to your lib.rs:

```
function = pallet_contracts::Call::COllectiveEvent
```